# Монтирование "своих" разделов при загрузке системы вместо дефолтных

Tags: linux, udev, device-mapper, fstab

Когда я устанавливал систему, я создал разделы и сгенерировал fstab. Вот его содержимое:

```
# /dev/sda3
UUID=abe3b587-3a5f-47d6-8f66-2df758e70665   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
# /dev/sda1
UUID=D2C4-B10A          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2
# /dev/sda2
UUID=23349153-86c4-495a-a78d-1034090f3cb1   none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

С помощью **device-mapper** я создаю виртуальное устройство, которое транслирует все запросы на реальное устройство. Для примера, пусть реальное устройство будет /dev/sda3, а виртуальное /dev/mapper/root_part.

Создаю я это в правиле udev демона. Вот сами правила:

```
KERNEL=="sd*",SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="abe3b587-3a5f-47d6-8f66-2df758e70665",RUN+="/lib/udev/create_virtual.sh %k"
KERNEL=="sd*",SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="remove",ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="abe3b587-3a5f-47d6-8f66-2df758e70665",RUN+="/lib/udev/remove_virtual.sh"
```

В свою очередь там выполняются скрипты:

**create_virtual.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 0 32359055360 basic_target /dev/$1 0 | dmsetup create root_part
exit 0
```

**remove_virtual.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
dmsetup remove root_part
exit 0
```

basic_target - самописный модуль ядра, скопированный (с некоторыми изменениями) из [этой](http://techgmm.blogspot.ru/p/writing-your-own-device-mapper-target.html) статьи.

Моим решением было поправить fstab так, чтобы монтировался не сам корневой раздел, а его соответствующий виртуальный. Для этого мне нужно было, чтобы демон udev создал это виртуальное устройство, прежде чем начнёт обрабатываться fstab. Но тут возникли проблемы. Указывая приоритет правила слишком высокий, оно не срабатывало, потому что, как я позднее понял, устройство получает UUID в одном из следующих правил. Постепенно снижая приоритет, я добился, что эта ошибка перестала возникать, однако появилась новая - устройство, на которое я собираюсь делать виртуальное, переходило в состояние "занято". При этом аналогичные проделки с флешкой эту ошибку не выдавали: виртуальное устройство создавалось и монтировалось в соответствии с добавленной строкой в fstab. Из чего я сделал вывод, что /dev/sda3 уже оказывалось примонтировано.

Не добившись своего, я решил просто убрать из fstab строку с root разделом и монтировать устройство прямо из скрипта create_virtual.sh. Но удаление строк из fstab ни к чему не приводило. Я даже полностью очищал fstab - система продолжает грузиться нормально.

У меня вопрос, как заставить систему использовать иные устройства при монтировании разделов?

Кроме того, если есть более правильные методы решения моей проблемы, то я бы очень хотел их услышать.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне нужно написать свой виртуальынй диск? Типа initrd(innitramfs) в котором бы создавалось виртуальное устройство?

Comment: разделы у вас монтируются в initrd. соответственно, если вы хотите, чтобы корень монтировался с помощью вашего модуля, вам надо как минимум включить его в initrd. ну и осуществить там же все необходимые манипуляции.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin понял, буду пробовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

корневой раздел у вас явно монтируются в [initrd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd).

соответственно, если вы хотите, чтобы он монтировался с помощью вашего модуля, вам надо как минимум включить этот модуль в initrd.

ну и осуществить там же все необходимые манипуляции с *dmsetup*.

Comment: Спасибо! Направление ясно. Собираю initramfs с помощью утилиты mkinitcpio. Если я правильно понимаю, то раздел /dev создаётся и заполняется именно в initramfs (иначе, где брать устройства монтирования). Однако, правила udev срабатывают как-то неполностью... Если, например, указать SYMLINK+="..." и написать в конфигурационном файле монтировать эту ссылку как root раздел, то всё работает и ссылка создаётся. Но если я укажу RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo 123 > /dev/1.txt'", то никакой файл не создаётся...

Comment: Проблему запуска скриптов решил. По всей видимости в эту базовую файловую систему не входит /bin/bash. Указал /bin/sh - завелось.